# Set up php-fpm status page with php7 and apache

Tags: php, apache, fpm

I'm trying to set up and get php-fpm stats with a http call. I know it's possible to use the **service status** command, but I would like to get that from my browser.

I'm running php7, and apache, and this is what I did in my server configuration.

at apache side, I create a vhost with this :

```
<LocationMatch "/fpm-status">
             Order Allow,Deny
             Allow from 127.0.0.1
             ProxyPass fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
</LocationMatch>
```

In the php pool configuration (**/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**) I have this :

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data

pm = ondemand

pm.max_children = 1000

pm.start_servers = 150
pm.min_spare_servers = 50
pm.max_spare_servers = 400
pm.max_requests = 200
pm.process_idle_timeout = 5s
pm.status_path = /fpm-status
```

but after restart apache and php-fpm process, when I try with curl I get this output :

```
admin@ip-10-3-23-78:~$curl http://localhost/fpm-status
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /fpm-status
on this server.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
admin@ip-10-3-23-78:~$
```

And in the apache log file I have this :

```
==> /var/log/apache2/error.log <==
[Thu Aug 25 13:36:10.776665 2016] [access_compat:error] [pid 12608] [client ::1:23142] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
```

I would like to know how to really set this up. I've googled for long time and didn't get a precise answer, every one is trying his way. 
Who is reponsible to create the status page (**fpm-status** in my case)? When and how this page is generated (by php-fpm I guess)? 
What is the right way to set the page up and accessible from a browser?

Answer (score 19):

Might be a bit late now but I wanted to post a straight forward simple answer to this issue with php-fpm(7.1+)/apache(2.4) as most of the answers I found online were a bit convoluted. This is using the default php-fpm settings that require unix sockets vs port mapping.

1) Within `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf`, I have the following config options set for listen sock below and uncommented out:

```
listen = /var/run/php-fpm.sock

pm.status_path = /fpm-status
```

2) With my apache config `php-latest.conf` (or similar) I added a match that looked for fpm-status and set it to `proxypass` to the unix socket and run the fpm-status from fcgi. It also restricts it so only localhost can call it:

```
<LocationMatch "/fpm-status">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    ProxyPass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost/fpm-status
</LocationMatch>
```

3) Just simply run the `curl` command locally:

```
$ curl http://localhost/fpm-status
pool:                 www
process manager:      dynamic
start time:           16/Oct/2019:11:33:25 -0400
start since:          14
accepted conn:        12
listen queue:         0
max listen queue:     0
listen queue len:     0
idle processes:       38
active processes:     2
total processes:      40
max active processes: 5
max children reached: 0
slow requests:        0
```

Comment: I skipped the `listen` line and added `pm.status_path = /fpm-status` to the bottom of `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf`, found my default sock at `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` and added the modified `LocationMatch` entry at the top of my apache2 `000-default.conf`, restarted php-fpm and apache2, and this works great. Good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the simple, straightforward example

Comment: From a browser can do `http://localhost/fpm-status?html&full` for more details.

Answer (score 4):

I suffered the same problem and put a few hours in there to solve it for our installations. Unfortunately I can not answer all questions you have put in there, this is mainly a working solution for the tile "Set up php-fpm status page with php7 and apache"

Here we go (Ubuntu 16.04):

**Step 1: Things needed**
Just check if you installed this stuff similarly:

```
apt-get -y install apache2
apt-get -y install libapache2-mod-fastcgi php7.0-fpm php7.0
a2enmod actions fastcgi alias
systemctl restart apache2.service
```

**Step 2: Setup fastcgi**
In /etc/apache2/mods-available/fastcgi.conf (or similar) put the following:

```
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
        # Define a named handler
        AddHandler php7-fcgi .php
        # Generate an alias pointing to /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php[VersionNumber]-fcgi
        Alias /php7-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi
        # Configure an external server handling your upcoming requests (note where the alias is pointing towards)
        FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization

         # only on if fpm-status is match. You might want to put this into your concrete vhost.conf file. For the testing, fastcgi.conf should work.
         <LocationMatch "/fpm-status">
             # set the before defined handler here
             SetHandler php7-fcgi
             # use the handler for the action handling virtual requests
             Action php7-fcgi /php7-fcgi virtual
         </LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```

**Step 3: Check your /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**
Make sure do uncomment the status path:

```
pm.status_path = /fpm-status
```

**Step 4: Secure the page (optional)**
Before going into production, it is certainly wise to secure this somehow, e.g.:

```
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
 Allow from [Some-IP]
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: mod_proxy_fcgi was created to better facilitate FPM usage compared to mod_fastcgi, please see https://serverfault.com/questions/783173/differences-between-mod-fastcgi-and-mod-proxy-fcgi/783176

Answer (score 4):

If you run other web-applications on your apache-server it is likely that one of them ships with an `.htaccess` file that interferes with handling the `/staus` page (or whatever you named the page in the php-fpm pool-configuration).

I recently came across that with a nextcloud instance. Within the nextcloud-(apache)-configuration whitelisting the URL and disabling the `.htaccess`-overrides for this path (`RewriteEngine Off`) made the page accessible in my case.
Be sure to replace the path to the socket with the correct path (this is stock Ubuntu 16.04 example).

```
<FilesMatch "^ping|status$">                                                       
  RewriteEngine Off
  SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock|fcgi://localhost"               
</FilesMatch>
```

**Note** As pointed out in the comments, the proper directive would likely be `<Location "^ping|status$">` instead of `<FilesMatch>`.

The socket-path is defined at
`/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` (`listen = /run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`) in default ubuntu version.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use FilesMatch here, when these URIs simply aren't files, please see https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#whichwhen

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a permissions error, try adding

```
listen.mode = 0666
```

to **/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

That was necessary for me to get the entire fastcgi stack with php-fpm running properly although I'm still not able to view the status page and am getting a 404 error when I try.

Comment: It's really very bad idea to allow anybody to write (connect) to the PHP-FPM sockets. Just use correct `listen.owner` so that apache can access it.